# How to remove the last occurrence of a character within a string?

Tags: string, vb6

I'm currently writing a function that dynamically composes a sql-query to retreive a number of posts and I've run into a smaller problem.

Pseudocode:

```
if trim$(sSqlQuery) <> "" then

    sSqlQuery = "foo foo ) foo"

end if


if 1 = 1 then

    sSqlQuery = sSqlQuery & "bar bar bar"

end if
```

This function returns the correct sql-query most of the time, but due to some circumstances in the earlier functions before this one, the second if-clause will be triggered. Resulting in weird query-results.

What i need to do is to figure out how to remove the last occurrence of ")" within sSqlQuery before it appends the second set of query to the total query within the second if-clause.

In pseudo I think it'd look something like this:

```
if 1 = 1 then

   call removeLastOccurringStringFromString(sSqlQuery, ")")

   sSqlQuery = sSqlQuery & "bar bar bar"

end if
```

However, i find it really hard to get a grasp on the `Right()` `Left()` and `Mid()` functions.

What I have tried is this:

```
nLen = InStrRev(sSqlSokUrval, ")") ' To get the positional value of the last ")"
```

After that i'm completely lost. Since if I substring this with `Mid()` i'll only get the ")" and nothing else.

Any thoughts and/or hint's on how to go about solving this will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'Searches subject and removes last (and *only* last) occurence of the findstring
Function RemoveLastOccurenceOf(subject, findstring)
    Dim pos
    'Find last occurence of findstring
    pos = InstrRev(subject, findstring, -1, vbBinaryCompare)  'use vbTextCompare for case-INsensitive search

    if pos>0 then 'Found it?
        'Take left of subject UP UNTIL the point where it was found
        '...Skip length of findstring
        '...Add rest of string
        RemoveLastOccurenceOf = Left(subject, pos - 1) & Mid(subject, pos + len(findstring))
    else 'Nope
        'Return entire subject
        RemoveLastOccurenceOf = subject
    end if
End Function
```